# How to test your query first before running it sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I made a silly mistake at work once on one of our in house test databases. I was updating a record I just added because I made a typo but it resulted in many records being updated because in the where clause I used the foreign key instead of the unique id for the particular record I just added

One of our senior developers told me to do a select to test out what rows it will affect before actually editing it. Besides this, is there a way you can execute your query, see the results but not have it commit to the db until I tell it to do so? Next time I might not be so lucky. It's a good job only senior developers can do live updates!.

Comment: You can: (1) take a backup before you do anything potentially dangerous, or (2) create a database snapshot, or (3) start a transaction (`BEGIN TRANSACTION`) so you could roll back in case of a mistake .....

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky no need it is a reasonable question as it is

Comment: If it's any consolation, I've done worse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First assume you will make a mistake when updating a db so never do it unless you know how to recover, if you don't don't run the code until you do,

The most important idea is it is a dev database expect it to be messed up - so make sure you have a quick way to reload it.

The do a select first is always a good idea to see which rows are affected.

However for a quicker way back to a good state of the database which I would do anyway is

For a simple update etc

Use transactions

Do a `begin transaction` and then do all the updates etc and then select to check the data

The database will not be affected as far as others can see until you do a last commit which you only do when you are sure all is correct or a rollback to get to the state that was at the beginning

Comment: I assume you're talking about hand-entering these queries via some database tool like query analyzer or running separate queries, where `end transaction` is called after the data is checked.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus that is what the question implies - if in code I would also ways test SQL via tsql or other command line before running code calling SQL the main reason is that you can test before the transaction is committed

Comment: I wasn't questioning your advice, but was curious as to how to implement the ideas.

Comment: Once the transaction has been committed, can it be rolled back at a later date? Lets say I messed up but we don't find out till a week later when someone else happens to need the record I deleted

Comment: @Ageis No but you have tests too catch the error and with a test db I would expect it to have been restored to a known star before then

Comment: Thanks alot Mark. I'll stick with the backup principle. Btw in my defense I did do a backup of the db before the update. I knew am crap at sql. I have a problem with attention to detail. But for some reason mssql wasn't having it when I tried to restore it.

Answer (score 22):

It seems to me that you just need to get into the habit of opening a transaction:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE [TABLENAME]
SET [Col1] = 'something', [Col2] = '..'
OUTPUT DELETED.*, INSERTED.*       -- So you can see what your update did
WHERE ....;

ROLLBACK;
```

Than you just run again after seeing the results, changing ROLLBACK to COMMIT, and you are done!

If you are using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio you can go to `Tools > Options... > Query Execution > ANSI > SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS` and SSMS will open the transaction automatically for you. Just dont forget to commit when you must and that you may be blocking other connections while you dont commit / rollback close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you must test in a production database and you have the requisite permissions, then write your queries to create and use temporary tables that in name are similar to the production tables and whose schema other than index names is identical. Index names are unique across a databse, at least on Informix.

Then run your queries and look at the data.

Other than that, IMHO you need a development database, and perhaps even a development server with a development instance. That's paranoid advice, but you'd have to be very careful, even if you were allowed -- MS SQLSERVER lingo here -- a second instance on the same server.

I can reload our test database at will, and that's why we have a test system. Our production system contains citizens' tax payments and other information that cannot be harmed, "or else".

Answer (score 0):

For our production data changes, we always ensure that we use a `BEGIN TRAN` and a `ROLLBACK TRAN` and then all statements have an `OUTPUT` clause.  This way we can run the script first (usually in a copy of PRODUCTION db first) and see what is affected before changing the `ROLLBACK TRAN` to `COMMIT TRAN`

Answer (score 0):

#### Have you considered `explain` ?

If there is a mistake in the command, it will report it as with usual commands.

But if there are no mistakes it will not run the command, it will just explain it.

Example of a "passed" test:

```
testdb=# explain select * from sometable ;
                         QUERY PLAN                         
------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on sometable  (cost=0.00..12.60 rows=260 width=278)
(1 row)
```

Example of a "failed" test:

```
testdb=# explain select * from sometaaable ;
ERROR:  relation "sometaaable" does not exist
LINE 1: explain select * from sometaaable ;
```

It also works with `insert`, `update` and `delete` (i.e. the "dangerous" ones)